# How to sort $N$ fractions from finite set

Tags: algorithms, sorting

> We have $10^5$ fractions: $\frac{p}{2^q}$ such that $0 \leq p,q \leq 10$. 
>   Find (fast) algorithm which sorts them.

I ask you to look at my proposition and tell me your ideas. $\frac{p}{q}$ is represented as the ordered pair $(p, q)$.

On input we have an array `a`.

**My idea:**

```
for i = 1 to n 
do t[i] = a[i].first * 2^(10)
countsort (t)
bring results from t to a (remember about / 2^10)
```

**II Idea:**

```
for i = 1 to n do       
   t[i] = a[i].first * 2^(10)
{ now we have only integer numbers }
sort t by counting (as bucket use bits)
for i = 1 to n do
   a[i] = t/2^10
```

In this way we have O(n + log (10 * 1024)n) = O(14n).
What about this solution ?

Comment: I'm confused. Why can you not use any regular sorting algorithm (with a tailored comparison function)?

Comment: That's good question. This task is as excercise in book. So I think: how to sort it ? (why it is in this book - where is root) ?

Comment: I cannot understand your pseudocode at all. Mind explaining it a little more clearly? @user220688

Comment: Ok. I try it explain it later. What about your proposition ? :)

Comment: @Raphael Using counting sort is faster. There are less than $121$ possible fractions.

Comment: Seems tailor-made for counting sort.  So I don't understand what the poster is confused about.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, I see that there are less than 121 fractions. Nevertheless it isn't obvius how to sort it. Look at some fact: When you countsort it you will have array 2d [10][2^10]. It isn't small table (it is better to use comparison sort)

Comment: As $10 < 16 = 2^4$, you could segregate into $2^{10 - 4} = 2^6 = 64$ buckets, and then count sort each bucket.

Comment: What's your question?  "Tell me your ideas" is not a question.  This site is for specific, focused questions that admit a single answer.  How will you evaluate answers?

Comment: I edited my first post, could you look at it ?

Answer (score 2):

You can sort all $11^2$ possible fractions, and create a table mapping $p/2^q$ to its position in this ordering, and another table going the other way. Then you can use counting sort to handle $N$ fractions in time $O(11^2 + N)$. (Here the underlying constant is universal, not depending on the size of the domain.)

Comment: Sorry, why $O(11^2 N)$? I think it should be $O(N)$ for putting every number in bucket and then $O(11^2 + N)$ for forming resulting array. _I know that $O(11^2 N) = O(2N + 11^2)$ , just $O(11^2 N)$ is little confusing._

Comment: I edited my first post, could you look at it ?

Comment: Probably worth saying "counting sort" here.